# xpath has a null value which is messing up the lists

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

i am scraping the names, addresses and number of cars from a webpage using the code below.

However, every so often there is a null value for the number of cars.  Lets assume in the example below that the 8th dealer has a null number of cars returned so the lists returned are something like:

names = a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j

addresses = aa,bb,cc,dd,ee,ff,gg,hh,ii,jj

cars = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10

where dealer a at address aa has 1 car, dealer b at address bb has 2 cars etc but because dealer h at address hh has a null value of cars it is skipped and instead the code thinks dealer h has 9 cars and so dealer i and address ii has 10 cars and therefore dealer j at address jj is missed out because the list of cars has run out.

therefore, where the code returns a null value of cars, how do i replace that with 0?  and so, in the example above dealer h and address hh would have 0 cars and therefore dealer i at address ii has 9 and dealer j at address jj would have 10 cars

```
import scrapy

from autotrader.items import AutotraderItem

class AutotraderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "autotrader"
    allowed_domains = ["autotrader.co.uk"]

    start_urls = ["https://www.autotrader.co.uk/car-dealers/search?advertising-location=at_cars&postcode=m43aq&radius=1500&forSale=on&toOrder=on&sort=with-retailer-reviews&page=822"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//ul[@class="dealerList__container"]'):
            names = sel.xpath('.//*[@itemprop="legalName"]/text() ').extract()
            names = [name.strip() for name in names]
            addresses = sel.xpath('.//li/article/a/div/p[@itemprop="address"]/text()').extract()
            addresses = [address.strip() for address in addresses]
            carss = sel.xpath('.//li/article/a/div/p[@class="dealerList__itemCount"]/span/text()').extract() 
            carss = [cars.strip() for cars in carss]
            result = zip(names, addresses, carss)
            for name, address, cars in result:
                item = AutotraderItem()
                item['name'] = name
                item['address'] = address
                item['cars'] = cars
                yield item
```

Comment: The simplest answer is to reorganize your code so that instead of doing three separate xpath queries and trying to zip the results together, you do one top-level query to get the groups, and then, for each group, xpath the three subfields from the group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector loop is a bit confusing.

Here you loop through unsorted lists, where there's only one per age:

```
for sel in response.xpath('//ul[@class="dealerList__container"]'):
```

What you want is to loop through all list items:

```
for sel in response.xpath('//li[@class="dealerList__itemContainer"]'):
```

If you loop this way you can get names, addresses of each individual list item:

```
for sel in response.xpath('//li[@class="dealerList__itemContainer"]'):
    names = sel.xpath('.//*[@itemprop="legalName"]/text() ').extract()
    names = [name.strip() for name in names]
    addresses = sel.xpath('.//article/a/div/p[@itemprop="address"]/text()').extract()
    addresses = [address.strip() for address in addresses]
    carss = sel.xpath('.//article/a/div/p[@class="dealerList__itemCount"]/span/text()').extract() 
    carss = [cars.strip() for cars in carss]
    item = AutotraderItem()
    item['name'] = name
    item['address'] = address
    item['cars'] = cars
    yield item
```

Comment: That worked a charm, thanks.  One item of note for anyone that reads the above code, the solution is `for sel in response.xpath('//li[@class="dealerList__itemContainer"]'):` the example code with the variables names, carrs etc will need adjusting by changing names to name etc and getting rid of certain lines lines with the name.strip() etc in them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the results. You can use the `xpaths` in your scrapy project the way it is shown below:

```
class AutotraderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "autotrader"
    allowed_domains = ["autotrader.co.uk"]

    start_urls = ["https://www.autotrader.co.uk/car-dealers/search?advertising-location=at_cars&postcode=m43aq&radius=1500&forSale=on&toOrder=on&sort=with-retailer-reviews&page=822"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for items in response.xpath("//article[@class='dealerList__item']"):
            name = items.xpath(".//span[@itemprop='legalName']/text()").extract_first()
            address = ' '.join([' '.join(item.split()) for item in items.xpath(".//p[@class='dealerList__itemAddress']/text()").extract()])
            cars = items.xpath(".//span[@class='dealerList__itemCountNumber']/text()").extract_first()
            yield {"Name":name,"Address":address,"Cars":cars}
```

Partial output:

```
Midland Motors Leicester Street, Burton-On-Trent, Staffordshire DE14 3BA 2
Ns Cars 69 Eldon Street, Burton-On-Trent, Staffordshire DE15 0LT 1
RS Sales Nottingham Ltd Unit 1 TRINITY PARK, RANDALL PARK WAY, Retford, Nottinghamshire DN22 7WF 1
Adc Ltd Unit 3 HUCKNALL LANE, Nottingham, Nottinghamshire NG6 8AJ 5
```